# Can we use object as a key of an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variables, data-structures

I was given a short javascript code in an interview to give the output of that but I was not sure what will be the output of that. He creates a `var object` and assigns objects as indexes of that object using the array data structure. I did console that code after the interview but still do not understand how it is showing the output.

Here is the code

```js
var a = {};
b = { key: 'b'};
c = { key: 'c'};
a[b] = 123;
a[c] = 456;

console.log(a[b]); //what is the output of this console statement and explain why
```

Can anyone explain with javascript logic behind the output it shows?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no array in your example. `a`, `b` and `c` are all objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: yes but when assigning it with number there is array data structure is used

Comment: @DavidArias I have to look into that.

Comment: You can access the properties of an object with the dot notation (`b.key`) or with the bracket notation (`b["key"]`). The bracket notation has to be used when the property name is not a valid identifier (e.g. when there's a space in the name) -> [Property accessors - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object used as key's [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is `[object Object]` and that is what is used each time

```js
var a = {};
b = { key: 'b'};
c = { key: 'c'};
a[b] = 123; // sets a["[object Object]"]
console.log(b,a[b])
a[c] = 456; // ALSO sets a["[object Object]"]
console.log(b,a[b])
console.log(Object.keys(a))
console.log(a[b]);

console.log(a["[object Object]"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look to the object `a`, where you see the stringed object (with `toString()`)

```
[object Object]
```

as accessor.

Objects can have only strings as properties and with the latest [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), it could be this one, too.

```js
var a = {};
b = { key: 'b'};
c = { key: 'c'};
a[b] = 123;
a[c] = 456;

console.log(a[b]); //what is the output of this console statement and explain why
console.log(a);
```